# LECA in potting mix: Good or bad idea?

Tags: potting-soil

I've purchased a bag of LECA for use in hydroponics. Recently, I have taken out the pellets from a pot that is no longer used for hydroponics and then I stored the medium. I was thinking of using this medium as part of a soil mix, rather than on its own, for making a better-draining mix. Is this a good idea? Would Perlite be better in all cases? Is it all the same grain size? How would it perform compared to scoria, tuffa and pumice?